# Does Freenode IRC not support Tor exit nodes?

Tags: chat

Whenever I try using Freenode IRC with Tor, Freenode says my Tor node's exit IP is banned. Does Freenode IRC not support Tor exit nodes?

I get this error:

> -NickServ- This nickname is registered. Please choose a different nickname, or identify via /msg NickServ identify .
>   
> * You are banned from this server- Your tor exit node must not allow connections to freenode (tor exit node (chat.freenode.net:8000)).  Email tor-kline@freenode.net when corrected. (2015/6/16 04.12)

Comment: Sure it does, instructions are here: https://freenode.net/irc_servers.shtml *"Tor provides anonymous access to internet services, including IRC, and protects users' privacy from various forms of traffic analysis. The freenode network welcomes Tor users."*

Comment: @GregHewgill Then maybe I don't have the proper Freenode account.

Comment: It looks like you're not actually connecting to the Freenode hidden service. *"Connections to freenode directly from Tor exit nodes are not allowed"*. You have to connect to `irc://frxleqtzgvwkv7oz.onion`.

Comment: @GregHewgill: I'm going through a Tor proxy. I've tried it your way, too, but XChat doesn't seem to like onion addresses. It complains that maybe I typed the address incorrectly!

Comment: You may wish to read a tutorial such as https://anonops.com/xchat.html if you wish to use XChat with Tor. It's not as simple as just entering the hidden service address.

Comment: @GregHewgill XChat still doesn't understand recognize onion addresses…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24861/discussion-between-geremia-and-greg-hewgill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status on `#freenode` currently says:

> Due to ongoing abuse the tor-sasl hidden service has been temporarily disabled

Comment: They also posted to Twitter on 9 Feb 2015: ["Due to ongoing abuse we have had to temporarily disable tor-sasl hidden service. We'll provide an update on its status as soon as possible."](https://twitter.com/freenodestaff/status/564848187710906368)